# User-defined Component not leading to other screen in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I have a user-defined Component which contains Tile, I am using this Component to fill the first screen using FlatList, the problem occurred when I tried to move to next screen when I click on the Tile using navigation prop.

Tried to use this.props.navigation.navigate('next_screen') but unable to move and getting error undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')

```
first_screen

<FlatList
                data={[{key: 'a', imgSrc: require('./image.jpg')}]}
                renderItem = {({item}) => <ImageContent sourceImage = { item } /> }
            />

ImageContent

export default class ImageContent extends React.Component {
_toPriceLayout = () => {
 this.props.navigation.navigate('next_screen')
}
render() {

        return (
            <View style = {styles.content} >
                    <TouchableOpacity >
                        <Tile
                            imageSrc = {this.props.sourceImage.imgSrc}
                            title = {this.props.sourceImage.key}
                            onPress = {() => this._toPriceLayout()}
                        />
</TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
 )
    }
}
```

When clicked on ImageContent then it should navigate to next_screen.

Comment: Where does `this.props.navigation` come from? You'll need to pass this as a prop to `ImageContent`. If first_screen has it as a prop you can pass it along: `<ImageContent sourceImage = {item} navigation={this.props.navigation} />`.

Comment: @vishwa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379537/creation-of-a-new-component-with-navigation-fields/57380130#57380130

Comment: @azundo it worked, thanks for the quick reply